# SQL. Объединение результатов SELECT в одну строку, требуется замена полученных результатов на человекочитаемые

Tags: postgresql, select

Есть таблица:
tab1 (id, arg1,arg2)
где
arg1 - идентификатор сервиса,
arg2 - цифровой код, возможные значения: 1,2,3
у сервиса может быть несколько кодов, сочетание arg1,arg2 в таблице не может повторятся.

Нужно вывести в результате запроса SELECT в одну строку все цифровые коды, которые соответствуют данному идентификатору сервиса. Но проблема в том, что в строке должны быть не коды, а ресурсы, которые соответствуют этим кодам, например 1 - сайт, 2- электронная почта, 3 - телефон

```
SELECT 
ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(
case
when (select arg2 from tab1 where arg1=111)=1 then 'сайт'
when (select arg2 from tab1 where arg1=111)=2 then 'электронная почта'
when (select arg2 from tab1 where arg1=111)=3 then 'телефон'
end),',')
from tab1 where arg1=111
```

такое у меня не сработало

ожидаемый результат:
111;сайт, электронная почта

Comment: Конечно, группировки-то нету...

Comment: оно и не могло заработать. Если в таблице несколько записей с arg1=111 то подзапросы в when недопустимы, так как они должны были бы вернуть строго одну строку. Кроме того они там не имеют смысла, потому что проверять надо arg2 из текущей записи таблицы основной выборки. т.е. подзапросы `select arg2 from tab1 where arg1=111` надо заменить просто на `arg2`. И так как требуется группировка нескольких строк результата, то надо использовать аггрегирующую функцию, например string_agg

Comment: *в строке должны быть не коды, а ресурсы, которые соответствуют этим кодам, например 1 - сайт, 2- электронная почта, 3 - телефон* Вообще это дело бы в отдельную таблицу затолкать надо было, чтобы не хардкодить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
arg1,
string_agg(
case
when arg2=1 then 'сайт'
when arg2=2 then 'электронная почта'
when arg2=3 then 'телефон'
end,',')
from tab1 where arg1=111
group by arg1
```

Агрегатная функция string_agg появилась в [версии 9.0](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-aggregate.html). Если нужно для более ранней версии, укажите в вопросе

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT arg1, STRING_AGG( CASE arg2 WHEN 1 THEN 'сайт'
                                   WHEN 2 THEN 'электронная почта'
                                   WHEN 3 THEN 'телефон'
                                   END, ',' ) arg2_list
FROM tab1 
GROUP by arg1
```